# showing more than one label in the dataset and add % to the data

Tags: reactjs, charts, dataset, label

I have my dataset and I need to display 3 labels but when I add more it only displays one , and I want to be able to have label with different colors too , my other problem is that I want to add "%" to the data but It say "Expression needed " .

Here is my datasets :

```
datasets: [{
      labels: ["Book 1", "Book 2" , "Book 3" ],
      data: [8%, 24%, 92%, 30% , 5%],
      backgroundColor: ["yellow", "red", "blue", "blue" , "red" ],
      barThickness:30
    }]
```

Comment: are you using a react charts library to show the data? If yes, which is it? I want to replicate your situation. For the percentage, an idea is to use the decimals, instead of 8% use 0.08.

Comment: @EduardoTavarez I have used import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `labels` attribute is part of `data`, but is not an element of the `dataset` you should write it like this: `data={labels, dataset}`. Your data length and the number of colors should also match the number of labels. I added 2 more books (book4 and book5) labels so we have the same number of labels, data, and colors.

To add the `'%'` sign, you can modify the label as you want with the `options` object. With this object, you can provide a callback function to customize the labels. The namespace is `options.plugins.tooltip.callbacks`. More in here: [Tooltip | Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-callbacks)

The `label` you mention that it only displays 1 is not precisely a `label`, but the `legend` of the chart. Since the name of each book is right below each bar I removed the legend with the `options` object. The namespace is `options.plugins.legend`

Following is the `Bar` object and an image of how it looks

```
<Bar 
  width={100} 
  height={50} 
  data = {{
    labels: ["Book1","Book2","Book3","Book4","Book5"],
    datasets: [{
      data: [8, 24, 92, 30, 5],
      backgroundColor: ["yellow", "red", "blue", "orange", "pink"],
      
    }
  ]
  }}
  options={{
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      tooltip: {
        enabled: true,
        callbacks: {
          label: (context) => {
            let label = context.dataset.label || '';

              if (label) {
                  label += ': ';
              }
              if (context.parsed.y !== null) {
                  label += context.parsed.y + '%';
              }
              return label;
          }
        }
      }
    },
    
  }}
/>
```

[image]

If what you want is to show each bar and have a legend on top of each bar with the name of the book then what you need to do is to treat each bar as a different dataset. For each dataset, add the `book name` in the `label` attribute and for the `labels` array, leave only 1 value so it stays as one section, you can write whatever you want or leave it blank as `""`. In this case, the `legend` is necessary, so the only difference in the `options` object is that the `legend` attribute is omitted and set to its default: `true`

```
<Bar 
  width={100} 
  height={50} 
  data = {{
    labels: [""],
    datasets: [{
      label:'Book1',
      data: [8],
      backgroundColor: ["yellow"],
      
    },
    {
      label:'Book2',
      data: [24],
      backgroundColor: ["red"],
      
    },
    {
      label:'Book3',
      data: [92],
      backgroundColor: ["blue"],
      
    },
    {
      label:'Book4',
      data: [30],
      backgroundColor: ["orange"],
      
    },
    {
      label:'Book5',
      data: [5],
      backgroundColor: ["pink"],
      
    }
  ]
  }}
  options={{
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        enabled: true,
        callbacks: {
          label: (context) => {
            let label = context.dataset.label || '';

              if (label) {
                  label += ': ';
              }
              if (context.parsed.y !== null) {
                  label += context.parsed.y + '%';
              }
              return label;
          }
        }
      }
    },
    
  }}
/>
```

[image]

Comment: tysm , I really appreciate ur help !!

Comment: @Nothere the answer was updated with a solution that might be more suited for what you were looking for.

Comment: @Nothere as promised the question was updated with a solution to add the '%' beside the number. An image at the bottom is provided. If this was of your help, I will appreciate you mark this answer as the solution :)

Comment: TYSM IT DID WORK !!!